# Is there a dimensionless number for wave guide width and frequency vs turn radius?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, acoustics, waves

It seems like there should be a [dimensionless number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_numbers_in_fluid_mechanics) for wave guide width and frequency vs turn radius, but I have not been able to locate it or understand the proper application of one I am overlooking. I am currently evaluating acoustic waves, but an electrical wave dimensionless number would probably work with some adaptation.

For example, say I have 20khz acoustic radiation traveling down a pipe (wave guide) filled with water at STP. The pipe diameter is 10mm and the radius of curvature of a 180 degree bend is say 100mm.

I anticipate that mathematically it would be very hard to calculate the attenuation/distortion at the other end of the wave guide. A dimensionless number would make it easier to test empirically then use similitude to predict a scaled system with the same value dimensionless number. But perhaps I am oversimplifying and no such number exists.

Comment: What do musicians do for trumpets? How is the mouthpiece frequency compared to the output frequency? trumpets have several 180 bends...